# Xpath finder for selenium using python -automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

I am trying to find an unique xpath for the below element, please advice if there are any better xpaths to make it for general text as I have currently given for that specific name.

```
<td tabindex="4" style="text-align: left;" title="name" class="">Name</td>
```

xpath i am using: //td[@title='name']

here if the name is changed with something else in the code, this wouldn't work, could someone help me identify unique xpath which works in general for any text. Thanks!

Comment: We'll need to see more detail of the element and DOM before answering.

Comment: You're concerned that the title attribute might change?  That's the nature of testing - any web element attribute can change, even ID, which is the preferred locator if present, and in your DOM example, it isn't.  While the text itself might change, it's less likely that the attribute title will change, so your current xpath is about as non-fragile as you're going to get in this example.

Comment: @BillHileman is correct.  If you have access to edit the source code you could add an `id` attribute and find by ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate (using **and** / **or**) multiple attributes of element to find the element precisely .

```
By.xpath("//td[@title= 'name' and contains(text(), 'Name')]")
```

**However we need to see more details of the code and your DOM of page to find element.**
There will always be some element which will never change in the page(like name of table) using that as a relative point ,we can refer to the row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to find the **XPath** of any element is to go to the developer options and select the markup of the element you want XPath of.

Right Click -> Copy -> **XPath**

I believe this is the simplest way. And you will also where you are doing wrong.

Screenshot attached for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used the general syntax - "//td[text()='{}']" and passing the name parameter when i define a method so that it won't be specific to one and others can test using the same locator with their name changed when someone else uses the testcase.

Thanks everyone for your response!